# SQL wrong COUNT after two NATURAL JOINs

Tags: sqlite, join, count, where-clause, natural-join

[image: Database]

> How many movies in the database were produced by Pixar Animation Studios?
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> 16
> 14
> 18
> 20
> ```

My incorrect solution

```
SELECT COUNT(movie_id)
FROM productioncompanies
NATURAL JOIN movies
NATURAL JOIN productioncompanies
WHERE production_company_name = "Pixar Animation Studios"
```

```
COUNT(movie_id)
4803
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre]

Comment: [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join `productioncompanies` to `productioncompanymap`.
The table `movies` is not needed because the details of the movies are irrelevant:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM productioncompanymap m NATURAL JOIN productioncompanies c
WHERE c.production_company_name = 'Pixar Animation Studios';
```

or, with an `INNER` join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM productioncompanymap m INNER JOIN productioncompanies c
ON c.production_company_id = m.production_company_id
WHERE c.production_company_name = 'Pixar Animation Studios';
```

or, with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM productioncompanymap
WHERE production_company_id = (
  SELECT production_company_id 
  FROM productioncompanies 
  WHERE production_company_name = 'Pixar Animation Studios'
);
```